# Unable to create neptune cluster using btoto3

Tags: amazon-neptune

We are not able to create neptune cluster using this python boto3 library, and boto3 function is given below

```
**Functions is:**
import boto3
client = boto3.client('neptune')
response = client.create_db_cluster(
    AvailabilityZones=[
        'us-west-2c',  'us-west-2b',
    ],
    BackupRetentionPeriod=1,
    DatabaseName='testdcluster',
    DBClusterIdentifier='testdb',
    DBClusterParameterGroupName='default.neptune1',
    VpcSecurityGroupIds=[
        'sg-xxxxxxxxx',
    ],
    DBSubnetGroupName='profilex',
    Engine='neptune',
    EngineVersion='1.0.1.0',
    Port=8182,
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'purpose',
            'Value': 'test'
        },
    ],
    StorageEncrypted=False,
    EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication=False,
    DeletionProtection=False,
    SourceRegion='us-west-2'
)
```

Error message is also given below

```
**error message :**
when calling the CreateDBCluster operation: The parameter DatabaseName is not valid for engine: neptune
```

could you please help to fix this ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I will take a look at your code and see if I can figure out what is wrong. For specific Amazon Neptune questions you may also want in the future to post to the support forum at: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=253

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `DatabaseName` just use `DBClusterIdentifier` and that will become the name of your cluster. The `DatabaseName` parameter is not needed when creating a Neptune cluster.